# Java, Where to place public enums

Tags: java, static, enums, global

I am exploring Java. Where is a good place to place enums and other things you would like to globally access?

For instance if you need access to daysOFtheWeek in all parts of your package, is there a place to put it where you wont have to qualify it when you use it. I was tempted to put it in a public static class but there seems to be no such thing.

Thanks!

Comment: Where classes go is a question of package organization and depends entirely on the organization of the rest of the project and your personal preference. If you don't want to qualify enums [`static import`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/static-import.html) is your friend.

Comment: Unless they're truly only for use by a single class, I always make them a public class, in their own source file.

Answer (score 1):

Simply make an `enum` in your package and define it with the `public` modifier... it does not have to be nested within a class.

Edit: I just noticed you said that you mentioned you don't want to qualify it. That's only possible if you nest it within a class and use it within or you import statically.

Comment: That isn't true, you can also statically import the enum values and then you don't have to qualify them.

Comment: That's true for any enum OR class, but yeah you're right.

Answer (score 1):

You should not decide according to where you use the enum. You should decide according to where you would look for it, i.e., where it belongs. For examples DaysOfTheWeek should belong to a Calendar or Date class in the package called (e.g.) time. Because there you would search for it.

You can avoid qualifying the package via imports and avoid qualifying the class via static import.

Note that enums are classes. An enum inside a class is just a nested class.

Comment: Thank you Andy for making it precise. I edited my post.

Comment: Thanks for the insite. I was thinking of an enum that would be globally accessable. As was mentioned, I would look for it globally. If I understand correctly, enums (& const & vars?) can be placed in a global class then statically imported. If they are needed locally then use a nested static class. Hope I got this right. If I may, why would you place an enum inside a nested class rather than in the class itself as a member?